# Asp.Net with EF better structure of project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

When creating an ASP.Net MVC project with a database, can I create a DAL class library at the beginning, where there would be model classes and access to the database, and then add this library to the Web project? Is it better practice to write entities in a Web project in the Models folder?
I want to create EF code first

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, but mine is that you should start in the simplest way possible.  You can always refactor later.

Answer (score 0):

I put my entities, DbContext(s), and repository classes in a separate assembly (Domain) and reference that from my web applications. If it were a small enough application then a Domain folder within the web application is certainly enough separation. It's strictly for organization sake.

What I don't recommend is attempting to pull everything out to abstract away from Entity Framework.  This involves a lot of relatively complex code to pull off, or it sacrifices performance and capabilities that EF can provide for your project.

For example, in my case both the web project and Domain assembly would hold references to EF. This is because my repository classes return `IQueryable<TEntity>` in their methods, and my controller also is responsible for the unit of work which will bound the DbContext. To leverage this, the web project will need a reference to EF.  I have seen numerous attempts to abstract EF away so that web projects don't need a reference to Entity Framework. IMHO this is a huge waste in effort in complex code or sacrifices so much that EF can do for a project. For instance you can introduce complex parameters such as `Func<Expression<T>>` to perform filtering and then also need to worry about sorting expressions, pagination, eager loading, etc.  Or you do away with the flexibility and performance of being able to reduce EF queries based on just what the circumstance needs by having your domain assembly classes (services or repositories) returning DTOs or detached entities. This leads to a lot of boilerplate code, and/or significant performance pitfalls.

So in short, when looking at whether to break functionality out into a separate assembly or not, it's important to look at the reasons for wanting to do it. Overall, aiming for simplicity is the best advice I can give.